# PHP - directAdmin web API

Tags: php, directadmin

i trying to create new database on my shared web hosting with **[directAdmin web control API](http://www.directadmin.com/api.html)**. i use below code to connect to directAdmin and create database but when i open php script, it not logged in to direct admin and showing login page .

```
include 'httpsocket.php';

$sock = new HTTPSocket;
$sock->connect('xx.xx.xx.xx',2222);

$user = getenv('xxxxxxx');
$pass = getenv('xxxxxxx');

$sock->set_login("${user}","${pass}");

$sock->set_method('POST');

$sock->query('/CMD_API_DATABASES',
       array(
            'action' => 'create',
            'name' => "Test101",
            'user' => "dbuser",
            'passwd' => "$pass",
            'passwd2' => "$pass",
));

$result = $sock->fetch_body();

echo $result;
```

Comment: what's in `var_dump($result)`?

Comment: var_dump -> string(1228)

Comment: i remove getenv("username") and getenv("password") and put username and password diretly in variables then problem solved . but i don't know why

Comment: `getenv("username")` will return the user that's running the php. which is apache or iis app pool identity account. you don't need that; you simply need db user's credentials. putting username and password directly is the right way to do it.

Comment: Do you still need the answer?